# Postgres SET UNLOGGED takes a long time

Tags: postgresql, alter-table, postgresql-9.5

Running Postgres-9.5. I have a large table that I'm doing `ALTER TABLE table SET UNLOGGED` on. I already dropped all foreign key constraints targeting the table since FK-referred tables can't be unlogged. The query took about 20 minutes and consumed 100% CPU the whole time. I can understand it taking a long time to make a table logged, but making it unlogged doesn't seem difficult... but is it?

Is there anything I could do to make it faster to set a table unlogged?

Comment: Maybe it's waiting for a lock? https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: I was monitoring it by querying `pg_stat_activity` every few seconds and didn't see the `waiting` column set true, plus I saw consistently high CPU usage that would indicate that it's not waiting. Also, I know there were no other queries running at all since it was in an isolated testing database.

Comment: @NickBarnes Ah, then that's the solution. Seems strange to me that setting unlogged would require a rewrite, but I don't really know how Postgres works under the hood.

Comment: Ah. In that case, with my specific hardware, it could be faster for me to create a new unlogged table and move data into it using multiple processes (my disks+cache are fast enough to not bottleneck). Thanks.

Comment: @Nick: I think there is enough substance in your comments to put it an acceptable answer.

Comment: Yes, @NickBarnes, I'll accept your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SET UNLOGGED` involves a table rewrite, so for a large table, you can expect it to take quite a while.

As you said, it doesn't seem like making a table `UNLOGGED` should be that difficult. And simply converting the table *isn't* that difficult; the complicating factor is the need to make it crash-safe. An `UNLOGGED` table has an additional file associated with it (the [init fork](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-init.html)), and there's no way to synchronise the creation of this file with the rest of the commit.

So instead, `SET UNLOGGED` builds a copy of the table, with an init fork attached, and then swaps in the new [`relfilenode`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html), which the commit can handle atomically. A more efficient implementation would be possible, but not without changing the representation of unlogged tables (which predate `SET UNLOGGED` by quite a while) or the logic behind `COMMIT` itself, both of which were deemed too intrusive for this relatively minor feature. You can read the discussion behind the design on the [pgsql-hackers list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/31724.1394163360%40sss.pgh.pa.us#31724.1394163360@sss.pgh.pa.us).

If you really need to minimise downtime, you could take a similar approach to that taken by `SET UNLOGGED`: create a new `UNLOGGED` table, copy all of the records across, briefly lock the old table while you sync the last few changes, and swap the new table in with a `RENAME` when you're done.